# Google Apps Script will not allow me to send outgoing e-mails

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script

This simple script should send an e-mail to the prescribed e-mail address ; however, it only works if the emailAddress I used is my logged in gmail account.  If I change that e-mail address to anything other than the e-mail address that I am currently logged in as, like my other msn/gmail accounts, it fails.  The [tutorials](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/sending_emails#section1) given seem to demonstrate that you can send e-mails to anyone.

My code:

```
function sendEmails() {
    var subject = "Homework Update"
    var messageBody= "testing the message";
    var emailAddress = "example1@gmail.com";
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress,subject,messageBody);
}
```

Error Message: "Failed to send email to example@gmail.com (line 7, file "Code")Dismiss"

Comment: Works fine for me...This might be a dumb question but have you authorized MailApp to send mail as you?

Comment: Yes, the request came up when I ran the script and I gave it permission.  Do you need google domain or some paid service for the script to work?

Comment: How about using the [GmailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app) instead? `GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress,subject,messageBody);`

Comment: Same result when using GmailApp.sendEmail.  The script works fine when not being ran under my google educator account, but when using my school e-mail it fails with the same error. "Failed to send...."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried running the script while logged in with a different e-mail account and the script worked fine.   I investigated further and found that my domain administrator does not have mail enabled for our google accounts. I work at a school and we use Microsoft Exchange server for e-mail.  I will be contacting the IT department tomorrow to see if there is anyway I can get the mail application enabled for scripting. Hopefully this post will help anyone with a similar problem.